# How to download a file using curl in php?

Tags: php, curl

How can I use Curl to download a file in PHP if the headers are set to true? can I also get the filename and extension of file?

Example PHP code:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$fp = fopen($strFilePath, 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
```

Comment: Did these answer work for you? If yes then please the most useful as correct for other's help.

Answer (score 7):

**Download file or web page using PHP cURL and save it to file**

```
<?php
/**
* Initialize the cURL session
*/
$ch = curl_init();
/**
* Set the URL of the page or file to download.
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
'http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&topic=t&output=rss');
/**
* Create a new file
*/
$fp = fopen('rss.xml', 'w');
/**
* Ask cURL to write the contents to a file
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
/**
* Execute the cURL session
*/
curl_exec ($ch);
/**
* Close cURL session and file
*/
curl_close ($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: OP said `if the headers are set to true`, which implies he want to do it with CURLOPT_HEADER set to true, it also implies OP want capture headers. this answer does not explain how to do either of those things =/

Comment: Shouldn't `fclose` be within a `finally`, so that the file is closed even if an Exception is thrown?

Answer (score 6):

I belie you have found your answer by now. However, I'd like to share my script that works well by sending a json request to a server which returns the file in binary, then it downloads on the fly. Saving is not necessary. Hope it helps!

> NOTE: You can avoid converting the post data to json.

```
<?php

// Username or E-mail
$login = 'username';
// Password
$password = 'password';
// API Request
$url = 'https://example.com/api';
// POST data
$data = array('someTask', 24);
// Convert POST data to json
$data_string = json_encode($data);
// initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Execute cURL and store the response in a variable
$file = curl_exec($ch);

// Get the Header Size
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
// Get the Header from response
$header = substr($file, 0, $header_size);
// Get the Body from response
$body = substr($file, $header_size);
// Explode Header rows into an array
$header_items = explode("\n", $header);
// Close cURL handler
curl_close($ch);

// define new variable for the File name
$file_name = null;

// find the filname in the headers.
if(!preg_match('/filename="(.*?)"/', $header, $matches)){
    // If filename not found do something...
    echo "Unable to find filename.<br>Please check the Response Headers or Header parsing!";
    exit();
} else {
    // If filename was found assign the name to the variable above 
    $file_name = $matches[1];
}
// Check header response, if HTTP response is not 200, then display the error.
if(!preg_match('/200/', $header_items[0])){
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($header_items[0], true).'</pre>';
    exit();
} else {
    // Check header response, if HTTP response is 200, then proceed further.

    // Set the header for PHP to tell it, we would like to download a file
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name);

    // Echo out the file, which then should trigger the download
    echo $file;
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Working code is great. Thank you. Just awarded the bounty.

Comment: @Karma uhm.. this code is not downloading a file with PHP, it is PROXYING a file with php, and it's not doing a good job either, being way slower and more memory-hungry than required, this script would do it much faster, benchmark it: http://paste.debian.net/1170460/

Comment: The reason for bounty. The answer assumed that there is an auth required (which is excellent because in real world scenario, you will use object storage and probably download from an object storage), using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");` instead of `header` will reveal header info to the user who uses Network tab of Web Inspector. From security POV, and real world usage, this was the most appropriate answer. Also, if a file did not require Auth (I still assume app uses object storage like S3, DO Spaces, etc) then they can give a direct link instead.

Answer (score 4):

Below is a complete example that uses a class. The header parsing is more elaborate then it can be, cause I was laying the base for full hierarchial header storage.

I just noticed init() should reset a lot more variables if it wants to be possible to reuse the instance for more URL's, but this should at least give you a base of how to download a file to a filename sent by the server.

```
<?php
/*
 * vim: ts=4 sw=4 fdm=marker noet tw=78
 */
class curlDownloader
{
    private $remoteFileName = NULL;
    private $ch = NULL;
    private $headers = array();
    private $response = NULL;
    private $fp = NULL;
    private $debug = FALSE;
    private $fileSize = 0;

    const DEFAULT_FNAME = 'remote.out';

    public function __construct($url)
    {
        $this->init($url);
    }

    public function toggleDebug()
    {
        $this->debug = !$this->debug;
    }

    public function init($url)
    {
        if( !$url )
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Need a URL");

        $this->ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,
            array($this, 'headerCallback'));
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,
            array($this, 'bodyCallback'));
    }

    public function headerCallback($ch, $string)
    {
        $len = strlen($string);
        if( !strstr($string, ':') )
        {
            $this->response = trim($string);
            return $len;
        }
        list($name, $value) = explode(':', $string, 2);
        if( strcasecmp($name, 'Content-Disposition') == 0 )
        {
            $parts = explode(';', $value);
            if( count($parts) > 1 )
            {
                foreach($parts AS $crumb)
                {
                    if( strstr($crumb, '=') )
                    {
                        list($pname, $pval) = explode('=', $crumb);
                        $pname = trim($pname);
                        if( strcasecmp($pname, 'filename') == 0 )
                        {
                            // Using basename to prevent path injection
                            // in malicious headers.
                            $this->remoteFileName = basename(
                                $this->unquote(trim($pval)));
                            $this->fp = fopen($this->remoteFileName, 'wb');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $this->headers[$name] = trim($value);
        return $len;
    }
    public function bodyCallback($ch, $string)
    {
        if( !$this->fp )
        {
            trigger_error("No remote filename received, trying default",
                E_USER_WARNING);
            $this->remoteFileName = self::DEFAULT_FNAME;
            $this->fp = fopen($this->remoteFileName, 'wb');
            if( !$this->fp )
                throw new RuntimeException("Can't open default filename");
        }
        $len = fwrite($this->fp, $string);
        $this->fileSize += $len;
        return $len;
    }

    public function download()
    {
        $retval = curl_exec($this->ch);
        if( $this->debug )
            var_dump($this->headers);
        fclose($this->fp);
        curl_close($this->ch);
        return $this->fileSize;
    }

    public function getFileName() { return $this->remoteFileName; }

    private function unquote($string)
    {
        return str_replace(array("'", '"'), '', $string);
    }
}

$dl = new curlDownloader(
    'https://dl.example.org/torrent/cool-movie/4358-hash/download.torrent'
);
$size = $dl->download();
printf("Downloaded %u bytes to %s\n", $size, $dl->getFileName());
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

when you say

> if the headers are set to true?

i'll assume you mean `if CURLOPT_HEADER is set to true`

several ways to do it, my personal favorite is to use CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION instead of CURLOPT_HEADER, but that does not, strictly speaking, answer your question. if you for some reason are absolutely adamant about using CURLOPT_HEADER, you can separate the body and the headers with strpos()+substr(),

eg:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_URL=>'http://example.org',
    CURLOPT_HEADER=>1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$header_body_separator = "\r\n\r\n";
$header_body_separator_position = strpos($response, $header_body_separator);
$separator_found = true;
if($header_body_separator_position === false){
    // no body is present?
    $header_body_separator_position = strlen($response);
    $separator_found = false;
}
$headers = substr($response,0, $header_body_separator_position);
$headers = trim($headers);
$headers = explode("\r\n",$headers);
$body = ($separator_found ? substr($response, $header_body_separator_position + strlen($header_body_separator)) : "");
var_export(["headers"=>$headers,"body"=>$body]);die();
```

gives you

```php
array (
  'headers' => 
  array (
    0 => 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK',
    1 => 'Age: 240690',
    2 => 'Cache-Control: max-age=604800',
    3 => 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
    4 => 'Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2020 09:47:18 GMT',
    5 => 'Etag: "3147526947+ident"',
    6 => 'Expires: Fri, 13 Nov 2020 09:47:18 GMT',
    7 => 'Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT',
    8 => 'Server: ECS (nyb/1D20)',
    9 => 'Vary: Accept-Encoding',
    10 => 'X-Cache: HIT',
    11 => 'Content-Length: 1256',
  ),
  'body' => '<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
(...capped)
```

but i don't recommend this approach, i don't recommend using CURLOPT_HEADER at all. instead i recommend using CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, eg:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = [];
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://example.org',
    CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => function ($ch, string $header) use (&$headers): int {
        $header_trimmed = trim($header);
        if (strlen($header_trimmed) > 0) {
            $headers[] = $header_trimmed;
        }
        return strlen($header);
    },
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
));
$body = curl_exec($ch);
var_export([
    "headers" => $headers,
    "body" => $body
]);
```

wich gives you the exact same result with much simpler code:

```php
array (
  'headers' => 
  array (
    0 => 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK',
    1 => 'Age: 604109',
    2 => 'Cache-Control: max-age=604800',
    3 => 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
    4 => 'Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2020 09:50:32 GMT',
    5 => 'Etag: "3147526947+ident"',
    6 => 'Expires: Fri, 13 Nov 2020 09:50:32 GMT',
    7 => 'Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT',
    8 => 'Server: ECS (nyb/1D2E)',
    9 => 'Vary: Accept-Encoding',
    10 => 'X-Cache: HIT',
    11 => 'Content-Length: 1256',
  ),
  'body' => '<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
(capped)
```

another option is CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, but i don't recommend using CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT in PHP because it's fking bugged: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65348

Answer (score 1):

To get both headers and data, separately, you typically use both a header callback and a body callback. Like in this example: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/callbacks.html

To get the file name from the headers, you need to check for a Content-Disposition: header and extract the file name from there (if present) or just use the file name part from the URL or similar. Your choice.