# How to get 100x100px and 200x200px profile pic from FQL?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

i am using this fql query this gives me 50x50px profile pic of user's friend

```
$FQLQuery = 'SELECT uid,sex,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())';
```

i want to get 100x100px or 200x200px by using fql only.

how i can get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the avatar using graph API by the following

```
$request_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
    $parfbuid . "?fields=picture.width(200).height(200)";
$requests = file_get_contents($request_url);    
$data = json_decode($requests);
$fsource = $data->picture->data->url;
$size=getimagesize($fsource);
```

and then I use GD library to get this image and save on disk. This way you can get whatever size you like of the rectangle avatar image.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) you can't. You will have to fetch one of the bigger images (`pic_big` maybe), and then make it into a square yourself with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You need only friends Facebook ids, profile images get by [CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177661/how-do-download-a-file-with-curl) or [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) from URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/FRIEND_ID/picture?type=normal
Supported types: small, normal, large, square

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the first result when searching for "fql square pic", I would like to point out that you can now select the pic_square field to get a 50x50 version of the user's profile picture.