# Extract audio from Google translate

Tags: translate

Is it possible to extract the audio from the Google translate? check this link, for example:

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=%22choose%22

So if you click on this, it will give you back the word "choose". Is there a way to download that speech in some form of audio file?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `php` with `curl` functions - that's usually what I turn to for these problems. See for example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177661/how-to-download-a-file-using-curl-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Actually was wondering about this myself, found this python script which can generate a mp3 file.

props go to original author ofcourse

https://github.com/hungtruong/Google-Translate-TTS/blob/master/GoogleTTS.py

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work (adapted from [the link I posted above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177661/how-to-download-a-file-using-curl-in-php?rq=1)):

```
<?php
/**
* Initialize the cURL session
*/
$ch = curl_init();
/**
* Set the URL of the page or file to download.
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=%22choose%22');
/**
* Create a new file
*/
$fp = fopen('audiofile', 'w');
/**
* Ask cURL to write the contents to a file
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
/**
* Execute the cURL session
*/
curl_exec ($ch);
/**
* Close cURL session and file
*/
curl_close ($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Depends a bit on your environment. It is php code. You can run it on your machine (if you have php installed - which is true by default on Mac OS or Linux; if you run windows you need to work a little harder). On my Mac, I paste this code into a file called "getaudio.php", then from the command line I type `php getaudio.php`. A couple of seconds later, the file `audiofile` appears in my directory.

Comment: Bottom line is this - you need to use a program that requests the file; python and php are the most commonly used languages to do that. If you are not familiar with either, then this is probably the wrong forum for asking your question - it may be that you are looking for a ready made tool (and that is explicitly not what this site is about - it is about writing programs).

Answer (score 0):

You will find, that the solutions mentioned in 2014 don’t work anymore, as there is no mp3 file as a response, but a base64 encoded audio. For details see here:

https://github.com/Boudewijn26/gTTS-token/blob/master/docs/november-2020-translate-changes.md

You can get a simple command line interface for extracting/saving the audio with tihs project:
https://github.com/Boudewijn26/gTTS (Google Text to Speach)

With this you can just do:

```
gtts-cli 'hello' --output hello.mp3
```

and have your audio file.