# how can i upload a file from a url that takes time to redirect to download link in php

Tags: php

How Can i upload a file from a web url(eg. http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Notepad%2B%2B%20Portable/NotepadPlusPlusPortable_6.6.3.paf.exe/download?accel_key=69%3A1400559000%3Ahttp%253A//portableapps.com/apps/development/notepadpp_portable%3A30f2052f%24595d5fff42fb788669369f5578117033130abe18&click_id=9cd19f44-dfd4-11e3-90c3-0200ac1d1d0b&source=accel) to my server(not local computer) using php??

Comment: I have edited the Question. And now, may be this question is okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file_get_contents`, `file_put_contents`

```
$filename = 'file.tar.gz';
$url = 'http://mirrors.ispros.com.bd/apache//httpd/httpd-2.4.9.tar.gz';
file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($url));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL for this or FTP

Here is the PHP manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

In case you want to download it to a server of which you have control over and running PHP on you can use CURL like so:
[How to download a file using curl in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177661/how-to-download-a-file-using-curl-in-php)