# Could not download the file to my upload directory using CURL

Tags: php, curl

i am trying to download the source file bellow using curl, but it is only creating destination file with 0 bytes, not downloading the original file and write the resource data. How can i solve this problem. I tried a example from this link: http://www.w3bees.com/2013/09/download-file-from-remote-server-with.html . But it also give the same result.

Anybody can help? my code is:

```
if(isset($_POST[$data_file_name_url])){
        $source = 'http://mr-greens-class.wikispaces.com/file/messages/Calender.ics';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
        $data = curl_exec ($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

        $destination = $dir.'/test.ics';
        $file = fopen($destination, "w+");
        fputs($file, $data);
        //file_put_contents($destination, $data);
        fclose($file);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download a file using curl in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177661/how-to-download-a-file-using-curl-in-php)

Comment: Possibly, but also: 1) why set SSLVERSION when not using the https protocol? 2) why open it for reading and writing (w+) if you only want to store (w)? 3) you can also try file_put_contents() depending on configuration... 4) try the curl command on the *nix (assuming you use *nix) prompt and use the verbose output and see if there's a problem there

Comment: I got the result given bellow after following your[ machineaddict ] provided link :

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\news\wp-content\plugins\dataPush\dataPush.php on line 195
Downloaded 0 bytes to

Answer (score 0):

You should remove SSLVERSION if not use (your URL start with http, so I assume it's not SSL)

```
$path = 'myfile.ics';
$final_url = 'http://mr-greens-class.wikispaces.com/file/messages/Calender.ics';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $final_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// sometimes needed to prevent problem by bot filtering
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.103 Safari/537.36'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if($data == false) {
        $errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $error_message = curl_error($ch);
        //error_log( "cURL error ({$errno}):\n<br/> {$error_message}");
}
curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents($path, $data);
```

Comment: @user3815550 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); is probably what you are looking for most. I tried the curl option on the prompt, but you need to specify that it needs to follow the redirects (it is SSL then though!)

Comment: @sonique I simply copy and past your code with editing the path but i still get the same result. Downloaded file size is zero.

Comment: I try with this code and I got a result, try to keep the same path, or  to change the URL just to test something else.